# how to tell Rust borrow checker that the thread will be joined before reference becomes dead

Tags: rust, thread-safety, borrow-checker

I'm writing a dummy program that uses a struct holding a string reference. I believe I specified the lifetimes correctly (at least, the compiler does not complain on the struct definition and method implementation).

```
use std::thread;

struct Wrapper<'a> {
    s: &'a String
}

impl<'a> Wrapper<'a> {
    fn new(source_str: &'a String) -> Self {
        Self {
            s: source_str
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let orig_str: String = "WORD".to_string();
    {
        let w = Wrapper::new(&orig_str);
        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
            println!("{}", w.s);
        });
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }
}
```

Anyhow I'm getting this error:

```
error[E0597]: `orig_str` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:18:30
   |
16 |     let orig_str: String = "WORD".to_string();
   |         -------- binding `orig_str` declared here
17 |     {
18 |         let w = Wrapper::new(&orig_str);
   |                 -------------^^^^^^^^^-
   |                 |            |
   |                 |            borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                 argument requires that `orig_str` is borrowed for `'static`
...
24 | }
   | - `orig_str` dropped here while still borrowed
```

I've read multiple times the borrowing theory and finally ran out of ideas.

To me it's obvious that even the `orig_str` is dropped in the end, the thread is joined earlier and nothing wrong is happening. Moreover, the `orig_str` lives longer than `w`. (If I remove the thread then everything compiles well).

So how else I can tell Rust compiler that my thread poses no harm?

Answer (score 1):

In order to make Rust understand that the threads will be joined at a certain point (then won't have any chance to be running and still using their references), the [**scopes**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.scope.html) have been introduced.

Here is your example slightly modified in order to use such a scope.

```rust
struct Wrapper<'a> {
    s: &'a String,
}

impl<'a> Wrapper<'a> {
    fn new(source_str: &'a String) -> Self {
        Self { s: source_str }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let orig_str: String = "WORD".to_string();
    let w = Wrapper::new(&orig_str);
    std::thread::scope(|s| {
        s.spawn(|| {
            println!("in thread: {:?}", w.s);
        });
    });
    println!("after thread termination, {:?} is still here", w.s);
}
/*
in thread: "WORD"
after thread termination, "WORD" is still here
*/
```

Comment: Nice, I'll check that out. And what about if I'm using `tokio::spawn` instead of `thread::spawn`? any solution I'm curious?

Comment: @IgorBezzubchenko Apparently it exists a [`tokio-scoped`](https://crates.io/crates/tokio-scoped) crate dedicated to the same purpose within tokio.